# Collect induction sensors data on flutter App

Tags: flutter, data-collection, sensors

I work in the industry and since a year I train myself in flutter.
One of my project is to install inductive sensors on conveyor and count the number of parts detected by the sensors.
The finality will be to have a phone app made with flutter where I can get the number of parts detected by sensors.

Please could you advice me on the technology, package, data collection system... I can use to communicate sensors with flutter App. What is the process to create that kind of app?

Thank you for your help

Comment: What I thought a the beginning is to have those sensors connected to a Bluetooth or wifi transmitter. Get the input from the sensor on a CSV or text file on a computer and found a way to automatically import the CSV or text file in a Firebase database to update the app. But I am not sure that it's the best solution.